# Not able to import google colab in python

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

Im trying to use sudo pip install google.colab and i get a lot of red output. sadly i cant give all of it since its too much and doesnt fit in the terminal but here some parts i think are relevant.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Colab uses `3.7.10 (default, May  3 2021, 02:48:31)` at the moment.

Comment: hey im running 3.9.5

Comment: Colab is unlikely to install on 3.9.5 so this is probably why you can't install it.